# WPF StylusPlugin/DynamicRenderer: How to detect type of Stylus device?

Tags: c#, wpf, tablet

I'm working on a WPF application running on a multi-touch tablet that currently uses an `InkCanvas` to capture ink. Unfortunatelly, the `InkCanvas` not only captures ink when a user uses a Stylus, but also when a user draws strokes with his fingers. As I am not interested in these finger-generated strokes, I am looking for a way to detect the type of the currently present Stylus device such that I can just ignore strokes generated by a finger completely.

Under normal conditions, I would use `Stylus.CurrentStylusDevice.TabletDevice.Type`. However, things get a bit complicated because of the `InkCanvas`. Regardless of the currently present Stylus device, `Stylus.CurrentStylusDevice` always returns `null` when called from a custom `DynamicRenderer` (which is responsible for rendering ink dynamically while the user is writing on the tablet/`InkCanvas`). I think the reason for this is the fact that a `StylusPlugIn` (like a `DynamicRenderer`) runs in its own thread before the normal WPF UI thread responds to the input...

So my question is: How can I detect the type of the currently present Stylus device from within a `StylusPlugin` like the `DynamicRenderer`?